# Updating EKS Managed NodeGroup is taking hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I've started working with EKS Managed Nodegroups managed by TF.
My cluster is running Cluster-Autoscaler and consists of 4 nodes in the group.
When I'm running TF and there's a new AMI version out, TF is updating the launch template and starting to replace the nodes.
The problem here is that this can take more than an hour for the entire update to roll out.
The only way so far that I could come with to reduce this time is by manually terminating one node at a time and letting the ASG replace this node with a new one.

Any idea if this behaviour is something common or is there something else that I can do to improve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1619). You can add your scenario to this issue to alert the team. The behavior is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-update-behavior.html).

Comment: Good answer, thanks.  The second link to docs pointed out that PodDisruptionBudgets (PDBs) were the problem in our case, and in fact a single deployment's PDB had zero disruption permitted, due to minReplicas being reduced.